# Populating a listbox with 2 columns from database

Tags: vb.net

i want to populate a listbox with 2 columns from database

Only 1 column is displaying in my listbox

I want to display FistName and LastName from my database but only FistName is showing.

Here are my codes:

```
 Try
        connection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Nikko Jaze Fabellon\Documents\ASRASIM.accdb")
        connection.Open()
        ds = New DataSet
        tables = ds.Tables
        dataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT [FirstName],[LastName] from [Personnel] where [Status] = 'Activated' ", connection)
        dataAdapter.Fill(ds, "Personnel")
        Dim view1 As New DataView(tables(0))
        With personnelList
            .DataSource = ds.Tables("Personnel")
            .DisplayMember = "FirstName"
            .ValueMember = "ID"
            .SelectedIndex = 0
        End With

        connection.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: MS ACCESS, im new in programming so for now im using MS ACCESS and not SQL.

Comment: SQL is a language not a DB - your SELECT statement is SQL.  You could add a FullName to the SQL Select statement as an alias:  `"SELECT ... FirstName + ' ' + LastName As FullName ...`  Keep First and Last in the SQL if you need them for other reasons

Comment: is that so? thank you mate. any recommendations on where i can read about sql.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/index.htm

Comment: You also do not absolutely need the DataAdapter, DataView or DataSet.  You could use a DBCOmmand object to fill a DataTable and use it as the DataSource - NET will provide a free DataView for you.  But you should be disposing of the Connection and DBCommand object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just force your query to return both fields joined together in this way (And do not forget the field ID used in the ValueMember)

```
Dim cmdText = "SELECT ID, [FirstName] & ' ' & [LastName] as FullName 
               FROM [Personnel] 
               WHERE [Status] = 'Activated'"

dataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmdText, connection)
dataAdapter.Fill(ds, "Personnel")
Dim view1 As New DataView(tables(0))
With personnelList
    .DataSource = ds.Tables("Personnel")
    .DisplayMember = "FullName"
    .ValueMember = "ID"
    .SelectedIndex = 0
End With
```

Notice that this syntax is valid for MS-Access. I am not sure if you can use the same syntax to concatenate two fields in other database systems.

Comment: Wow!! i dint know that. Tnx mate its working now. hey any recommendation on where i can study about sql statements?.

Comment: I already gave you a link to one @MaikoFujimaru You should also read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: tnx guys, this is a nice site my friend recommend me if i have questions ask here ahaahah tnx i will study hard